# Ubuntu 16.04 and vim-youcompleteme plugin install fail

Tags: 16.04, vim

OS: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

vim: already installed with python by source from `apt-get source vim`

then, `apt-get install vim-youcompleteme`, it is ok for now.

I check the guide in, and say: `vam install youcompleteme`

**BUT**, in 16.04, it is failed, and give INFO:

`Info: ignoring 'youcompleteme' which is neither removed nor broken`

At the same time, it is works well in Mint17.

I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

Installation process of YouCompleteMe has been modified. Use the instructions provided in the [GitRepo Help file.](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#ubuntu-linux-x64)

> Make sure you have Vim 7.4.143 with Python 2 or Python 3 support. Ubuntu 14.10 and later have a Vim that's recent enough.
>
> Install YouCompleteMe with [Vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim#about).
>
> Remember: YCM is a plugin with a compiled component. If you update YCM using Vundle and the ycm_core library APIs have changed (happens rarely), YCM will notify you to recompile it. You should then rerun the install process.
>
> Install development tools and CMake.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake
> ```
>
> Make sure you have Python headers installed.
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
> ```
>
> Compiling YCM with semantic support for C-family languages:
>
> ```
> cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
> ./install.py --clang-completer
> ```
>
> Compiling YCM without semantic support for C-family languages:
>
> ```
> cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
> ./install.py
> ```

Answer (score 1):

That means it's already installed most likely.

If you run `vam` on its own it should show its status.

Maybe try `vam remove youcompleteme` then re install.

Maybe try `sudo vam remove -w youcompleteme` to do a system wide remove, then reinstall.